# How do I create a closed beta on Steam?

Tags: steam, playtesting, beta

As per suggestion I'm splitting [How do I create a closed beta on the App Store?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131594/how-do-i-create-a-closed-beta-on-steam-google-play-or-the-app-store) up.

Can I upload the game I'm developing to Steam as a closed beta, so I could generate a couple of keys/tokens for my testers? I'm hoping to only publish the game for the public after I'm happy with the game as it's offered on Steam, as a complete user experience which includes the installation process.

If this is not the usual workflow, how should I do it?

Comment: Also see related: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/186718

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Steam you do it by creating a branch in SteamWorks (under SteamPipe) which you set a password for. You then upload your build and push it live in that branch (again it's under SteamPipe). Anybody who has access to that branch (you've generated a key for + has the password) can opt in to the beta and will be given that build.