# How do I create a closed beta on Google Play?

Tags: google-play, playtesting, beta

As per suggestion I'm splitting [How do I create a closed beta on the App Store?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131594) up.

Can I upload the game I'm developing to Google Play as a closed beta, so I could generate a couple of keys/tokens for my testers? I'm hoping to only publish the game for the public after I'm happy with the game as it's offered on Google Play, as a complete user experience which includes the installation process.

If this is not the usual workflow, how should I do it?

Comment: Could the negative voter please give some feedback as to why it's not a valid or useful question?

Comment: You asked the same question three times.

Comment: @Krythic If you take a look at the original question (linked in the first sentence) you can see Philipp's suggestion to create a separate one for each platform as this promises a better chance of finding an expert answer for each case. Do you still disagree that it's useful?

Comment: [Google Play: Set up alpha/beta tests](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

Comment: Yeah a lack of actually reading both questions lead to someone giving you a down-vote. People should actually take time to understand that google play and the app store are two different things with different systems for different devices. Jeez guys don't be so harsh on people if your not even willing to read the questions properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Sign in to your Google Play Developer Console.
2. Select an app.
3. On the left menu, select APK > Beta testing.
4. If you see *Choose a testing method*, select the drop-down arrow.
5. Select *Set up Closed Beta Testing* > *Create list*.
6. Type a name to identify your list of testers

...
 ?. PROFIT

This way only invited people will be able to install and test your game :3

link: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en